# Meteor changing template

Tags: meteor

Maybe I misunderstood Dynamic Templates, but if I understood correctly, this is basically putting a placeholder in one template where you can display other templates and swap them as you wish.

What I need is slightly different, because the template itself needs to be dynamic, depending on the document it should display, and yet I cannot know in advance exactly what the different combos will be required since these could change often.

Say we have a collection of documents, but there documents have different parameters:

```
{
    p1: "...",
    p2: "...",
}
{
    p1: "...",
    p3: "...",
}
{
    p2: "...",
    p3: "...",
    p4: "...",
}
```

And, most importantly, the parameters can change quite often in any new document being added. We have a JSON schema for these different types of documents, each defining the params to be used, but these can change dynamically and often.

How would we create a template that displays/edits objects from this collection?

Is something like this even possible in Meteor?

Comment: Is the possible universe of keys known *a priori* or is it unpredictable?

Comment: It actually is unpredictable, but it is received from another service in a defined JSON form describing name, type and so on.

Comment: ok, so you need to render arbitrary JSON basically? This is like building a JSON viewer (of which there are many). What kind of UX are you driving for?

Comment: I'm fine with building the UI from JSON, I just don't know if it is then possible to bind it to the database in a Meteor way? Right now, when I build the UI with the Meteor template, the data is bound and reacts to the changes in the DB, but thats when I know the structure and am able to bind a a specific text field to a specific item in the document. But would this also be possible in the "unpredictable documents" case?

Comment: In your example there is no key that is common across the 3 documents so how would you bind a field to a "specific item"? It would have to be based on something! And yes, you can just stuff JSON into a mongo document without worrying about the schema, that's the easy part.

Comment: So, it is not possible then... I thought so, but wanted to double-check to be sure since I'm no expert...